# Why is Time Machine not deleting old files?

Tags: backup, time-machine

I have Time Machine running on a 4TB external drive. I have a 1TB internal drive. There is 200GB free on the external drive. The backup is 400GB. Time Machine should delete the old backups but it's not doing that. Strangely, the Preference panel is saying "Oldest backup: March 19, 2020 // Latest backup: March 20, 2020" even though there are 422 backups on the backup drive from 2019-05-01 through 2020-03-20.

This makes no sense. Is just another Time Machine bug (one of many).

[image]

[image]

[image]